# Hide tableitem border with j2me polish

Tags: netbeans, blackberry, java-me, j2mepolish

I created a tableitem to list the items. I want to hide the border. Any examples or source code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.j2mepolish.org/cms/leftsection/documentation/design/visual-guide/gui-item-tableitem.html

Look at `complete-border` and `border` css values